# Firebase Authenticationを使って一定期間未ログインだったユーザーのログインができない

Tags: xcode, android-studio, firebase, swift5

Firebase Authenticationに登録したメールアドレスとパスワードでログインできません。登録して2週間以上経過していますが、一度もログインしたことがありません。
未ログインのアカウントを自動で無効化するといった機能がFirebase Authenticationには搭載されているのでしょうか？

また、Firebase Authenticationのアカウントセッションについては長期間とだけ記載されており、具体的な期間が分からないです。

何が原因でしょうか？